# People bypassing anti-swear system by using duplicate letters

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Ok so, I made an anti-swear system in discord.py, but you can easily bypass it. Here's an example: let's say "cat" is a swear word, well you can just do "ccaatt" and the bot won't detect it. How do I fix this?
Here's the code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    try:
      if message.author.bot:
        return
      if client.user in message.mentions:
          response = f"Hello! I'm Stealth Bot. My prefix is `-`. To see a list of commands do `-help`."
          await message.channel.send(response)
          print(f"{message.author.name} pinged me in {message.channel}!")
          pass
      if message.channel.id == 828667602351161354 or message.channel.id == 820049182860509206:
        pass
      else:
        if profanity.contains_profanity(message.content):
            await message.delete()
            warnMessage = f"Hey {message.author.mention}! Don't say that!\n*You said ||{message.content}||*"
            await message.channel.send(warnMessage, delete_after=5.0)
            print(f"{message.author.name} tried saying: {message.content}")
            channel = client.get_channel(836232733126426666)

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Someone tried to swear!", colour=0x2D2D2D)
            embed.add_field(name="Person who tried to swear:", value=f"{message.author.name}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="What they tried to say:", value=f"{message.content}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Debug:", value=f"{profanity}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Debug 2:", value=f"{message.content.lower}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Channel they tried to swear in:", value=f"<#{message.channel.id}>", inline=False)

            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            pass
      await client.process_commands(message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: [In CS it can be difficult to explain the difference between the easy and the virtually impossible](https://xkcd.com/1425/)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: https://pypi.org/project/better-profanity/   https://pypi.org/project/profanity-filter/   https://pypi.org/project/profanity-check/

Comment: Good luck. With unicode substitutions and combining characters, misspellings, 6500 human languages, the "Scunthorpe" problem, huge controversy and subjectivity over what even is profanity, and good old human ingenuity at play, it's probably an unsolvable problem. Definitely one to use a 3rd party solution for, possibly a paid for service if there are consequences e.g. content that minors are going to interact with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
def replaceDoubleCharacters(string):
    lastLetter, replacedString = "", ""
    for letter in string:
        if letter != lastLetter:
            replacedString += letter
        lastLetter = letter
    return replacedString
```

---

```
# your code
if profanity.contains_profanity(message.content) or profanity.contains_profanity(replaceDoubleCharacters(message.content)):
    await message.delete()
# more of your code
```

`replaceDoubleCharacters` does exactly what it says. But you should keep in mind that people trying to bypass restrictions is a very common thing, and they will find other ways.

Comment: I got a problem with this though. I can say "bitchhh" for some reason.. (and some more swear words like cuunt)

Comment: Yes there are some cases with orderer letters where the .join method doesn't apply right. I wrote a better version, which should take everything into account. I updated it in the answer.

Comment: Oh nvm you fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I got one issue with this though, users can still bypass it doing something like this: "f u c k" or "b i t c h". How do I fix that?

Comment: You should probably ask this in a seperate question?

Comment: it got deleted. pog

Comment: What you are asking for is actually very hard to implement. How is the program supposed to know, when a space is used to sperate letters, and when it is used to seperate words? This is like AI level stuff. The best I could come up with is something like this https://pastebin.com/FdhKnyMG
Remember that this function is very limited because of the shear complexity of the problem...

Comment: erm i got a problem.. people are bypassing the anti-swear system by just doing "vfuck"

Comment: Please don't ask questions in comments. Just ask a new question instead! :)

Comment: Okay. i am typing random words to get the minimum characters required

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, is to use the `difflib` like this:

```py
import difflib

swearWords = ["cat", "dog"]
swearWordsFound=difflib.get_close_matches("stringToCheck", swearWords)
```

Comment: How would I use this with better_profanity?

Comment: Why would you want to use it with better_profanity? The `get_close_matches` looks for closest matches of a given word so I don't understand your question honestly... Can you give more details?

Comment: I just prefer using better_profanity cause it automatically adds bypasses like sh1t, b1tch etc

Answer (score 0):

lets say you are using your own discord bot just do this:

if message.contains('swear words here')

(Only if your bot is in python and add 2 underscores before and after the contains function)

Answer (score -1):

To be honest a proper discord Mod using discord.py require Machine Learning and AI no matter how much u format the messages there will be many flaws there was a competition on kaggle to rate toxic messages. The 1st place solution was transformed into a module called `detoxify` in python if you actually want a very good anti swear and have a good compute and a bit of storage on the cloud pc you are deploying on then I think you can use it. I would recommend using heroku it is widely used for deploying ML applications.